# Marking scale degrees

Tags: scales

I am marking down the scale degrees for this exercise. I think the tonic in this piece is D as it feels like a resolution. To find the first scale degree in the exercise I counted up from D until I got to A, which was five steps. So This is the fifth scale degree, which is correct. Then I did the same for the other degree and got to two (as E is right above D). The answer, however, is apparently 7. Where did I go wrong? Does this mean that the tonic is actually F? Because that doesn't sound right to me.

[image: Beethoven sonatina 3 Mvt. 2 scale degrees]

Comment: The writers may have made a mistake, unless there was some kind of modulation which doesn't really give any indication of.

Comment: Why do you think the apparent answer is: E natural is 7?

Comment: That E is definitely 2, not and 7. Is it possible the notated score is wrong? (Although having a C-sharp there seems very odd to me.)

Comment: If this is from a text or work book please provide the title.  One of two things could have happened.  (1) it's a typo in the answer key or (2) there is some other info you have not given us that make the exercise more complex, e.g. a key change etc.  Though option (2) does not seem likely.

Comment: I probably misunderstand the question. I would write the degrees of the chords and not of the key. What is meant by degrees? To which scale do they refer?  Referring to the key D the answer of Tim is correct. But the degrees would mean to me a) the Roman Numbers indicating the function of the chords i.e.: 1. bar  =  I and bar  2. = V or VII (Dominant without - I haven't looked up the accompaniment)   or  b) the notes  in question A and E referring to the harmony in this case both are the 5th degree of the  underlying chords  are D and A.. But the answer 7 will be wrong anyway.

Comment: @ggcg - were there a key change, A wouldn't be 5. And it's not B minor either.

Comment: @Richard - why is C# odd? The line seems to be D centred.

Comment: @Tim I mean in context; it results in a tritone leap down to G, and that C# never really resolves back up to tonic. The C# itself certainly isn't odd in D major!

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli "scale degree" is the English term that corresponds to German *[Tonstufe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonstufe).*  It's usually a numeric system corresponding to movable do solfege, so one might say that the dominant seventh chord comprises scale degrees 5, 7, 2, and 4.

Comment: @Tim, I didn't say that was the key change.  It was an open ended comment meant to encourage more from the OP.

Comment: @Richard - I can't seem to find your C#! Although I wondered whether *if* C# *was* the answer, would LvB have written a tritone. I think not. Ah, I see where your (hypothetical) C# is!

Comment: A would be 7 in B minor. So are you saying you were told 7 was the correct answer for the first note or the second one? What was the correct answer for the other?

Comment: @phoog: that's what I also meant by the R.N.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli in my experience, to avoid ambiguity with chord analysis, Arabic numerals are typically employed with a caret or circumflex written above, to avoid ambiguity with functional harmonic analysis.  Saying that a V7 chord comprises V, VII, II, and IV would be confusing indeed.  This is however conspicuous by its absence in the Wikipedia articles.

Comment: See my answer! why OP doesn't apply the R.N. is unclear to me ...

Comment: To answer the two main questions: Yes this is the full piece of music used in this exercise and 7 was the correct scale degree according to the writer. These exercises came from some online site for teaching music theory, I guess the author just made a mistake here.

Comment: @RobertC - not to be snarky, but try to find a good college textbook for theory/harmony instead of the web. You should be able to find one with quizes and answers. Also, lots or course syllabi are online so you can see textbooks assigned in actual couses.

Comment: @RobertC. - authors should not be making mistakes in anything that will be used for education that will be available for public consumption in perpetuity - or even on the internet. Get it right or leave it out.

Comment: @RobertC.another benefit of using a well known text is that many folks on the forum will be familiar with them - so actually teach from them - so the Q & A goes better with a known textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 sharps and an anacrucis of A, yes, it's in D major. That A is 5th, and the E note will be 2 (or possibly 9), there's no way it could be 7. Had the dot been on the space below, making it C♯, then, yes, it would be 7.

With the F♯ in the key sig. the tonic would never be F anyway.

Comment: Of course, E is also the (unraised) seventh degree of the F# minor scale, not that there's anything to suggest F# minor here.

Answer (score 0):

This confusion can be explained - to me - only like this:

A bar 1 is the 5th of the tonic DF#A, correct answer D = I (-> I not 5)

E bar 2 is the  the 3rd of the chord C#EG (7th degree of major D), correct answer: C# = vii dim5 (-> vii not 2).

Comment: I might go with the 2nd bar harmonising as a V, therefore A dominant 7, so *containing* an E note, but that doesn't make **the** note itself 7. The question in the quiz or the answer itself is flawed. That's all. I know typos can (and do!) occur, but in test situations really do need to have been ironed out. Unforgivable.

Comment: I have upvoted  your answer, Tim, as I agree with this interpretation. But I was looking for an alternativ explanation, and this would be that *degree* is not referring to the notes A  and E but the chords  AC# E and C#EG (A and C#m-5). But in this case the solution must be I-vii (-5) and this should be written in R.N. (and A=5 would be wrong.)